Why doesn't this data live update on change in my vue component?
I'm updating a relatively complicated component (because it is used in many places on a website, and the update, although being pretty simple in principle, can't change the html structure of the component because it will break things elsewhere). I need to add a certain footnote in some cases when window size is below 768px in width.
Basically, my solution is to have a span that shows v-if="mobile_footnote" is returning true. So I was thinking, on mounted I'd check if the footnote is passed as true from the parent, and if so, I'd have a listener that checks the size of the innerWindow and when it's below 768 I'd set the mobile_footnote to true, and when it's larger I'd set it to false. However it's not behaving how I'd expect.
So I have a prop that is passed from the parent called footnote (default: null), and a data value called mobile_footnote (default: false)
I have this in my mounted()
if (this.footnote) {

  // Set the mobile_footnote to true on window load, this works fine
  let width = window.innerWidth;

  if (width < 768) {
    this.mobile_footnote = true;
  }

  // If user resizes, update mobile_footnote to true/false depending what's needed, this is broken
  let onresize = function() {
    let width = window.innerWidth;
    this.mobile_footnote = true;

    if (width < 768) {
      console.log('footer true')
      this.mobile_footnote = true;
    } else {
      console.log('footer false')
      this.mobile_footnote = false;
    }

    console.log(this.mobile_footnote)
  }

  window.addEventListener("resize", onresize);
}

The issue I'm coming across is that, although in console logs the data mobile_footnote does update at the correct window widths, it doesn't live update the v-if span except on refresh. Is there a reason the live update isn't working?
Based on Vue's lifecycle hooks it seems like it should update once data updates, right? Or am I misunderstanding the lifecycle hooks?

What am I missing?

Can you check reactivity for this.mobile_footnote via vue devtools or built-in functions?
Or share code with data() { return {} } part.

This issue is related to the scope of onresize not being the same scope as the component. Arrow function would fix the problem, e.g. const onresize = () => { ... }, but really with Options API all functions should be within the "methods" option of the component:
methods: {
  onresize() {
    let width = window.innerWidth
    this.mobile_footnote = true

    if (width < 768) {
      console.log('footer true')
      this.mobile_footnote = true
    } else {
      this.mobile_footnote = false
      console.log('footer false')
    }

    console.log(this.mobile_footnote)
  }
},
mounted() {
  if (this.footnote) {
    // Set the mobile_footnote to true on window load, this works fine
    let width = window.innerWidth

    if (width < 768) {
      this.mobile_footnote = true
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', this.onresize)
  }
},
// remember to remove event listeners before unmounting
beforeUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onresize)
}

Alternatively, I can't help but find the current solution over-engineered. Without using any of the above code, the footnote can be dynamically displayed based on screen size using CSS media query. Where the footnote element has class "footnote":
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .footnote {
    display: none;
  }
}


It definitely is overengineered but unfortunately I can't fix it via CSS because in order not to break structure elsewhere I ended up needing to add the mobile footnote inside a v-html next to something else. There might be a better way to do it but at this point it's time to move on hahaha. This helped me, thank you!
